# Кнопка автопрокрутки страницы с настраиваемой скоростью

Tags: javascript, html, css

Как написать код, что бы, нажимая на кнопку, страница медленно опускалась вниз? Желательно с регулируемой скоростью.
****Как тут:****
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Пожалуйста, исправьте вопрос, чтобы он отражал конкретную проблему с достаточным количеством деталей для возможности дать адекватный ответ.

Answer (score 0):

Можно использовать следующее:

```
$( "#button" ).click(function() {

  $( "#button" ).animate({
    height: "toggle"
  }, speedOfScrolling, function() {
    // Animation complete.
  });
});
```